# How to add a register 's content as an immediate argument in a mips instruction?

Tags: mips, mips32

I have a register called $offset which I can control. 
I would like to know how can I rewrite the lw command such that instead of the word off in

```
lw $a off($b)
```

I have to the content of the $offset register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIPS assembly doesn't support this.

What you will need to do instead is:

```
add $c $b $offset
lw  $a 0($c)
```